# Property created with @property performs differently

Tags: python-3.x, properties, decorator

```
>>> class test():
    name = 'tiger'
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.name = value
    
>>> class subtest(test): pass

>>> a = subtest('cat')
>>> super(subtest,subtest).name
'tiger'
```

When I use super(class, class) to access a normal property of class, it gets value of that property. However, when I rewrite that property with @property, it turns out to a property object, why and what happend?

```
>>> class test():
    name = 'tiger'
    def __init__(self,value):
        self._name = value
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self,value):
        self._name = value
        
>>> class subtest(test): pass

>>> super(subtest,subtest).name
<property object at 0x03AB6300>
```